# I am getting error in ionic InAppBrowser while passing URL

Tags: ionic3

I am using inAppBrowser to open an external URL in my app but in this.inAppBrowser.create function while passing URL it is opening into a new window as "localhost:8100www.google.com" instead of www.google.com.I am using Google Chrome but in Mozilla Firefox it is working fine

I enter code herehave tried putting "https://" before the link like this
this.inAppBrowser.create("https://"+ //my link) but this is not working in Firefox

```
<button expand="round" *ngIf="s.qmedia" (click)='showMedia(s.qmedia)'>
<ion-icon item-centre name="link">Open Link</ion-icon>

showMedia(qmedia:string) {
  var browser = this.inAppBrowser.create("https://" + qmedia, 
                                        '_system','location=no');
                    browser.show() }
```

expected is link should open in Chrome as well without putting "https://" before it in this.inAppBRowser.create()

Answer (score 0):

try like this

let options = 'location=yes,toolbar=yes,hidden=no';

let browser = this.iab.create('https://www.google.com/', '_blank', options);

Comment: hello, thanks for your response but that is not working